# Swift: Custom UIView subview with drawRect

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to implement custom drawing on the background of a `UITableViewCell`?

So far I have determined it is most likely to add a custom `UIView` subview to content view of the cell.

The problem is that the cell repaints sporadically when scrolled.

TestViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ListTableView: UITableView!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.item].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

CustomUIView:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class ColoredUIView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var barColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let barThickness: CGFloat = 3.0
        let barLeft: CGFloat = 5.0

        //Vertical Line
        let barPath = UIBezierPath()
        barPath.lineWidth = barThickness

        //move to the start of the vertical stroke
        barPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(
            x:barLeft,
            y:0))

        //add the end point to the vertical stroke
        barPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
            x:barLeft,
            y:bounds.height))

        //set the stroke color
        barColor.setStroke()

        //draw the stroke
        barPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

Comment: Drag a UIView from the Object Library to your prototype cell. Set its Class as ColoredUIView in the identity inspector.

Comment: Also you could subclass UITableViewCell and implement your drawing code there instead.

Comment: I had tried it like that but `func drawRect(rect: CGRect)` wasn't being called. I ended up changing the `Identifier` to another name and it suddenly came to life. Although now the draw colors go crazy when the list is scrolled.

Comment: Selecting a cell seems to trigger the draw call again and displays the correct color.

Comment: @KylePennington11 instead you can place a lable in your cell and apply background color on it. If you just want to draw a vertical bar with color.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Yes, that is what I have ended up doing with a UIView. But it would be nice to know how to do it if I wanted to make the drawing a bit more complex.

Comment: @KylePennington11 if you want to use `drawRect` of `UIView` for complex drawing then you need to track which cell it belongs. You need to make uiview a subview of Cell and then do it.